# Remove last digit from a numeric value in a column if only the value has 4 digits

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, azure

I would like to remove the last digit from a numeric field/value from an entire column only if the value has 4 digits either using SQL or Python.
Example:
Column name is Credit Score
Table name is T1
Example values are 888 and 8880, I would like to remove any values with 0 at the end but only if has 4 digits, as some values are like 740 and 7400.

Thank you,

Comment: do you want to update the existing table column?

Comment: Yes i would like to update the existing table column

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just `update` the column dividing the existing value by 10 if it is >= 1000 and ends in a 0.

```
update tablename
set credit_score = credit_score/10
where credit_score >= 1000 and credit_score%10 = 0
```

Comment: That came back to remove all lines, negative effect, once again trying to change it from 7400 to 740 if values are 4 digits as there is mix of 4 digit and 3 digit values in this numeric field.

Comment: did you use the same query as posted in the answer. I have edited it a few times. Try the latest one.

Comment: states requestId = 6669541cf447479f98e041ab3df8b606 errorComponent=Module. taskStatusCode=400. {"Exception":{"ErrorId":"InvalidSQLScript",,"Message":"Error 0069: SQL query \"update t1\r\nset credit_score = credit_score/10\r\nwhere credit_score >= 1000 and credit_score%10 = 0\" is not correct:\r\nSQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such column: credit_score"}}Error: Error 0069: SQL query "update t1set credit_score = credit_score/10where credit_score >= 1000 and credit_score%10 = 0" is not correct:SQL logic error or missing databaseno such column: credit_score

Comment: this runs on SQLlite suery ppossibly and the column name is straight up Credit Score

Comment: the erroe says the column `credit_score` doesn't exist. change it appropriately. if there is  a space between credit and score in the column name use "Credit Score" in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your needs on SQL Azure, please try to use the sql below.

```
update tablename
set credit_score = cast(replace(rtrim(replace(cast(credit_score as varchar), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') as int) 
where credit_score >= 1000
```

For example: 7400 => 74, 70400 => 704